# Selector for grandchildren, or how to anchor the selector on a known element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

Let's say I have a hierarchy of elements, with `#root` at its root. I can use `$('#root > * > *')` to get all its grandchildren. Is there any way I could do that if I already have `$('#root')`?

`$('#root').find('* > *')` is definitely not it, as it will happily "start" from any descendant for the first star, not just `#root` children.

Is there any function in jQuery that would "anchor" at the current element, starting with its children or itself? It's been bugging me for a while, and I couldn't find anything similar in the docs.

Comment: `.find()` is possibly the single most annoying jQuery traversal method, ever.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Either start the find expression with another `>` (this syntax is [documented](http://api.jquery.com/find)):

```
// This is functionally the same as $('#root > * > *')
$('#root').find('> * > *')
```

Or call [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) twice: once for its children and again for its grandchildren:

```
$('#root').children().children()
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the `.children()` thing, but... well, doesn't fit what I'm doing, I really wanted the selector thing. And the selector thing... wow, I never thought to try that, that's amazing. Any idea how solid it is? I'm a bit wary of it being undocumented - works now, but for how long?

Comment: @Amadan: I have no idea about that... it seems to have worked for quite some time now.

Comment: I've updated this post to reflect that this feature is now documented.

Comment: @JDB: About time it did. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, really helpful :)